# Runtime of while loop pseudocode

Tags: analysis, pseudocode

I have a pseudocode which  I'm trying to make a detailed analysis, analyze runtime, and asymptotic analysis:

```
sum = 0
i = 1
while (i ≤  n){

    sum = sum + i
    i = 2i
}
return sum
```

My assignment requires that I write the cost/runtime for every line, add these together, and find a Big-Oh notation for the runtime. My analysis looks like this for the moment:

```
sum = 0                1
long i = 1                  1
while (i ≤  n){        log n + 1

   sum = sum + i       n log n
   i = 2i              n log n
}     
return sum             1
```

=> 2 n log n + log n + 4       O(n log n)

is this correct ? Also: should I use n^2 on the while loop instead ?

Comment: Can you add parenthesis?  I see that either running indefinitely or running only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of integer arithmetic, the runtime is

```
O(floor(ln(n))+1) = O(ln(n)).
```

Let's step through your pseudocode. Consider the case that n = 5.

```
iteration#  i   ln(i)   n
-------------------------
1           1   0       5
2           2   1       5
3           4   2       5
```

By inspection we see that

```
iteration# = ln(i)+1
```

So in summary:

```
sum = 0             // O(1)
i = 1               // O(1)

while (i ≤  n) {    // O(floor(ln(n))+1)    

    sum = sum + i   // 1 flop + 1 mem op = O(1)
    i = 2i          // 1 flop + 1 mem op = O(1)
}
return sum          // 1 mem op = O(1)
```